# Do I open a connection every time I need to call to IndexedDB?

Tags: angular, typescript, indexeddb

I am developing a simple Angular application and I want to store some data in IndexedDB.

I have a service that initializes `private db: IDBDatabase;` in its constructor:
However, when I try to use the initialized DB, by the constructor, in another method call, this DB is never defined. I know that this probably has something to do with async calls, callbacks and promises but I can't figure out what ... so the only solution right now that I can think of is to call

```
window.indexedDB.open("MyTestDatabase", 1);
```

everytime

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Directory, Bookmark} from "./models";
import {connectableObservableDescriptor} from "rxjs/internal/observable/ConnectableObservable";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookmarksService {

    private db: IDBDatabase;
    private directoriesStoreName = "directoreis";
    private bookmarksStoreName = "bookmakrs";
    constructor() {
        console.log("Calling Bookmarks Service Constructor .... ");
        if (!window.indexedDB) {
            console.log("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB. Such and such feature will not be available.");
           
        }
        let openDBRequest: IDBOpenDBRequest = window.indexedDB.open("MyTestDatabase", 1);
        console.log("Let's see if the DB will open .. ")

        /**
         * The only place where a data can be defined is onupgradeneeded callback !
         * @param event
         */
        openDBRequest.onupgradeneeded = (event: any) => {
            console.log("onupgradeneeded fired");
            this.db = event.target.result; 
        };

        openDBRequest.onsuccess = (event: any) => {
            console.log("seems that db is opened ! ");
            console.log(event);
            this.db = event.target.result;
            this.db.onerror = x => {
                console.log("An error occurred while working with DB! ");
            }
        };

        openDBRequest.onerror = event => {
            console.log("can't open IndexedDB");
            console.log(event);
        }


getAllChildDirs(parentId: number): Directory[] {

    if (this.db) { // this is NEVER defined, why ?! 
        var os = this.db.transaction(this.directoriesStoreName).objectStore(this.directoriesStoreName);
        var request = os.index("parent_id");
        var dirs: Directory[] = [];
        request.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(parentId)).onsuccess = (event: any) => {
            var cursor = event.target.result;
            if (cursor) {
                // cursor.key is a name, like "Bill", and cursor.value is the whole object.
                console.log("Name: " + cursor.key + ", SSN: " + cursor.value);
                dirs.push(cursor.value);
                cursor.continue();
            }
        };
        return dirs;
    }
}
    }
```

Then I have a component like this:

```
export class DirectoriesListComponent implements OnInit {


    @Input() bookmarks: Bookmark[];
    @Input() directories: Directory[];
    isCollapsed = false;

    common: CommonService;
    bookmarksService: BookmarksService;

    constructor(commons: CommonService, bookmarksService: BookmarksService) {
        this.common = commons;
        this.bookmarksService = bookmarksService;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.directories = this.bookmarksService.getAllRootDirs(); // ALWAYS returns empty array ?! becuase the db is never defined ... 
        this.bookmarks = this.bookmarksService.getBookmarks();
        //listens on when button is clicked to collapse the menu !
        this.common.dirsMenuCollapsed.subscribe(val => {
            this.isCollapsed = val
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually the problem is that you don't control when the onsucess function will be called as it's a callback, and will be executed sometime that you won't control.

However you can do something to control it, check it out:

- You promisify the database connection opening and wait for it

Something like this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Directory, Bookmark} from "./models";
import {connectableObservableDescriptor} from "rxjs/internal/observable/ConnectableObservable";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookmarksService {

  private db: IDBDatabase;
  private directoriesStoreName = "directoreis"
  private bookmarksStoreName = "bookmakrs"
  constructor() {
    console.log("Calling Bookmarks Service Constructor .... ")
    // :refac: you can even call it from the constructor, but won't wait as the constructor can't wait async functions to be completed
    this.initializeDatabase()
  }

  private async getDatabase(): Promise<IDBDatabase> {
    // :refac: Now we create a Promise<IDBDatabase> and wait for it when needed
    return new Promise<IDBDatabase>((resolve, reject) => {
      //
      const openDBRequest: IDBOpenDBRequest = window.indexedDB.open("MyTestDatabase", 1)
      console.log("Let's see if the DB will open .. ")

      /**
      * The only place where a data can be defined is onupgradeneeded callback !
      * @param event
      */
      openDBRequest.onupgradeneeded = (event: any) => {
        console.log("onupgradeneeded fired")
        const db = event.target.result
        resolve(db)
      };

      openDBRequest.onsuccess = (event: any) => {
        console.log("seems that db is opened ! ");
        console.log(event)
        const db = event.target.result
        db.onerror = x => {
          console.log("An error occurred while working with DB! ");
        }
        resolve(db)
      };

      openDBRequest.onerror = event => {
        console.log("can't open IndexedDB");
        console.log(event)
        reject()
      }
    })
  }

  async initializeDatabase(): Promise<void> {
    if (!window.indexedDB) 
      return console.log("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB. Such and such feature will not be available.")
    else if (!this.db)
      this.db = await this.getDatabase()
  }

  async getAllChildDirs(parentId: number): Promise<Directory[]> {
    await this.initializeDatabase()
    if (this.db) {
      const os = this.db.transaction(this.directoriesStoreName).objectStore(this.directoriesStoreName)
      const request = os.index("parent_id")
      const dirs: Directory[] = []
      request.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(parentId)).onsuccess = (event: any) => {
        const cursor = event.target.result
        if (cursor) {
          // cursor.key is a name, like "Bill", and cursor.value is the whole object.
          console.log("Name: " + cursor.key + ", SSN: " + cursor.value)
          dirs.push(cursor.value)
          cursor.continue()
        }
      }
      return dirs
    }
  }
}
```

And as you are returning a promise, you should use await when calling it:

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
  this.directories = await this.bookmarksService.getAllRootDirs();
  this.bookmarks = await this.bookmarksService.getBookmarks();
  //listens on when button is clicked to collapse the menu !
  this.common.dirsMenuCollapsed.subscribe(val => {
    this.isCollapsed = val
  })
}
```

Comment: Is opening database a costly operation, my background is Java backend that is why I am asking such a questions :P \

Comment: No, mostly because you're using ```providedIn: root```, so this create a singleton instance for your service, which is appropriate. But that's a good questioning